# Confused about hosting a dynamic app with custom api with express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm little bit confused. I know how to serve user a dynamic page using Ejs with express. Usually when the user access the domain, the API in the domain responds with a page that is in the same domain. so we just have to host the API in a server.
Now i'm learning React on front-end and using express with MongoDB on the back-end. How to connect these front-end and back-end. How back-end serves the react app to the user. I searched on YouTube, but no one is talking about the back-end part, they are only talking about hosting the front-end part.
I don't know if i'm asking in the right way or not.but please help me.

Comment: Are you developing both the frontend(react app) and backend(express app) in the same codebase or different codebase?

Comment: @Tunmee in different bases

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to have one `web-server` to serve static files (the react app) and one `API server` (express) that exposes the API.

In order to consolidate both of these servers under one domain, you will need to use a `Reverse Proxy`. I would suggest using `Nginx` (inside docker).

```
                    +----------+
                    |          |
                    |  Client  |
                    |          |
                    +----+-----+
                         |
                         |  myDomain.com
                         |              
                     [INTERNET]
                         |
                         |
                         v  :80
                +--------+-------+
            /*  |                |   /api
     +----------+  Revese Proxy  +---------+
     |          |                |         |
     |          +----------------+         |
     | :8080                               | :3000
     |                                     |
+----+----------+                +---------+-----+
|               |                |               |
|  React        |                |  Express      |
|  (webserver)  |                |  (API server) |
|               |                |               |
+---------------+                +---------------+
```

Any request to myDomain.com will be checked. If the path contains /api the request will be passed to the Backend. any other request will be passed to the webserver that contains the SPA static file.

Comment: Should i avoid using '/' route to serve some other data in my api